# why the password is visible for a split second even after i am doing stty -echo?

Tags: passwords, expect, password-protection

i tried everything even removing the stty echo line but the password is visible for a split second after the user types his password.i am thinking its some timeout issue so i am trying withh all kind of timeout values with futile attempts

```
set timeout 30
stty -echo
send_user -- "Password for $username :"
expect_user -re "(.*)\n"
set timeout .000000001
set timeout 30
send_user "\n"
set timeout 30
set password $expect_out(1,string)
send -- "$password\r"
```

what could be the reason 
how can i handle this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried your code and it works fine for me. Which version of the `Expect` you're using?
By the way, I usually write like this:

```
stty -echo
send_user "Password: "
expect_user -timeout 3600 -re "(.*)\n"
stty echo
send_user "\r\n"
set passwd "$expect_out(1,string)"
```